# Test if a file has been downloaded Selenium/C# (Google Chrome)

Tags: c#, selenium

I'd like to click on a button that downloads a file **on click**, and test whether the expected file has been downloaded.

I've already googled this, but unfortunately didn't find any specific answer on this topic, lots of posts I found, are outdated (2014), I bet Selenium must've changed the API definition by now.

Answer (score 9):

This code verifies if the file is downloaded and then deletes it.

```
private static bool CheckFileDownloaded(string filename)
{
    bool exist = false;
    string Path = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + "\\Downloads";
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Path);
    foreach (string p in filePaths)
    {
        if(p.Contains(filename))
        {
            FileInfo thisFile = new FileInfo(p);
            //Check the file that are downloaded in the last 3 minutes
            if (thisFile.LastWriteTime.ToShortTimeString() == DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() ||
            thisFile.LastWriteTime.AddMinutes(1).ToShortTimeString() == DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() ||
            thisFile.LastWriteTime.AddMinutes(2).ToShortTimeString() == DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() ||
            thisFile.LastWriteTime.AddMinutes(3).ToShortTimeString() == DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString())
            exist = true;
            File.Delete(p);
            break;
        }
    }
    return exist;
}
```

Hope this helps. Code in **C#**.

Comment: FWR Test Runners from Resharper and MS Test Explorer seem to download files elsewhere - I was able to modify your solution - thanks!: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54635540/314291

Answer (score 5):

Use below code:-

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import java.io.File;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class FileDownloadVerify {

 private WebDriver driver;

 private static String downloadPath = "D:\\siva";
 private String URL="http://all-free-download.com/free-photos/download/in_love_cosmos_flower_garden_220378.html";

 @BeforeClass
 public void testSetup() throws Exception{
  driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile()); 
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
 }

  @Test
 public void example_VerifyExpectedFileName() throws Exception {
  driver.get(URL);
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='detail_content']/div[2]/a")).click();

     Thread.sleep(10000);
     File getLatestFile = getLatestFilefromDir(downloadPath);
     String fileName = getLatestFile.getName();
     Assert.assertTrue(fileName.equals("in_love_cosmos_flower_garden_220378.zip"), "Downloaded file name is not matching with expected file name");
 }


 @AfterClass
 public void tearDown() {
  driver.quit();
 }
public static FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile() throws Exception {

  FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
  firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
  firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
  firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir",downloadPath);
  firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/zip");

  return firefoxProfile;
 }
public boolean isFileDownloaded(String downloadPath, String fileName) {
 boolean flag = false;
    File dir = new File(downloadPath);
    File[] dir_contents = dir.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < dir_contents.length; i++) {
        if (dir_contents[i].getName().equals(fileName))
            return flag=true;
            }

    return flag;
}

private boolean isFileDownloaded_Ext(String dirPath, String ext){
 boolean flag=false;
    File dir = new File(dirPath);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    if (files == null || files.length == 0) {
        flag = false;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < files.length; i++) {
     if(files[i].getName().contains(ext)) {
      flag=true;
     }
    }
    return flag;
}

private File getLatestFilefromDir(String dirPath){
    File dir = new File(dirPath);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    if (files == null || files.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    File lastModifiedFile = files[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < files.length; i++) {
       if (lastModifiedFile.lastModified() < files[i].lastModified()) {
           lastModifiedFile = files[i];
       }
    }
    return lastModifiedFile;
}
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution would be to use a file watcher to detect the creation of the file.
It would allow you to wait for the download to start and to finish:

```
string folder = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + "\\Downloads";
using (var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(folder)) {

    // wait for new file to be created
    var result = watcher.WaitForChanged(WatcherChangeTypes.Created, 5000);
    if (result.TimedOut)
        throw new WebDriverTimeoutException("Dowmload failed");
    Console.WriteLine("Download started for : " + Path.Combine(folder, result.Name));

    // wait for the temporary file to be deleted
    var result2 = watcher.WaitForChanged(WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted, 10000);
    if (result2.TimedOut)
        throw new WebDriverTimeoutException("Dowmload failed");
    Console.WriteLine("Download finished for : " + Path.Combine(folder, result.Name));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly FileSystemWatcher has a strange behavior and it is very likelly that it will fail to sync well in your selenium tests.

Answer (score 2):

This is my generic C# solution

```
/// <summary>
/// Start a download and wait for a file to appear
/// https://stackoverflow.com/a/46440261/1141876
/// </summary>
/// <param name="expectedExtension">If we don't know the extension, Chrome creates a temp file in download folder and we think we have the file already</param>
protected List<FileInfo> ActAndWaitForFileDownload(
    Action action
    , string expectedExtension
    , TimeSpan maximumWaitTime)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(DownloadDirectory);
    var fileCountbefore = Directory.GetFiles(DownloadDirectory).Length;
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    action();

    var isTimedOut = false;
    var extensionFilter = $"*{expectedExtension}";

    Func<bool> fileAppearedOrTimedOut = () =>
    {
        isTimedOut = stopwatch.Elapsed > maximumWaitTime;
        var isFilePresent = Directory
                                .GetFiles(DownloadDirectory, extensionFilter)
                                .Length == fileCountbefore;

        return isFilePresent && !isTimedOut;
    };

    do
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Log($"Waited {stopwatch.Elapsed} (max={maximumWaitTime}) for download '{extensionFilter}'...");
    }
    while (fileAppearedOrTimedOut());

    var files = Directory
                    .GetFiles(DownloadDirectory)
                    .Select(s => new FileInfo(s))
                    .ToList();

    if (isTimedOut)
    {
        Log($"Timed out: {filenamesForLog}");
    }
    else
    {
        var filenamesForLog = string.Join(",", files.Select(f => f.Name));
        Log($"File downloaded: {filenamesForLog}");
    }

    return files;
}
```

This is the usage

```
// Wait for a PDF
var downloadedFiles = ActAndWaitForFileDownload(() => buttonElement.click(), ".pdf", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

Comment: this do not download file in specified directory ! how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

FWR, both test runners I tried (Resharper, and MS Test explorer) placed the Selenium files in the following folder.

```
MySolution\MyProject\bin\Debug\Downloads
```

In fact Se adds a `readme.txt` here containing:

> This folder is here for Selenium to download files in

However, I was able to modify @Sudeepthi's answer accordingly:

```
private static readonly string SeleniumDownloadPath = 
     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Downloads";
private static bool CheckFileDownloaded(string filename)
{
    var firstFile = Directory
        .GetFiles(SeleniumDownloadPath)
        .FirstOrDefault(fp => fp.Contains(filename));
    if (firstFile != default)
    {
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(firstFile);
        var isFresh = DateTime.Now - fileInfo.LastWriteTime < TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
        File.Delete(firstFile);
        //Check the file that are downloaded in the last 3 minutes
        return isFresh;
    }
    return false;
}
```