# How to verify Download file functionality?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I need to click Download button and verify if the file is downloaded. 
I am using Selenium WebDriver in C#.

Comment: [Does this answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36468876/test-if-a-file-has-been-downloaded-selenium-c-google-chrome)?

Comment: This works when File gets downloaded directly without any Save as dialog box. What if I get a Save as dialog box once I click download button?